# How can I test the DigitalOcean functions by doctl befor deploying to to a production namespace?

Tags: javascript, digital-ocean, serverless

First, I am new to use the DigitalOcean Functions, I have created some javascript namespace by `doctl serverless`, my question is how can I test a DigitalOcean functions by `doctl serveless` or something like that, befor deploying to a production? I want to run locally and do tests befor deploying.

I also had a look at the [doc](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/) and `doctl serveless -h`.

Comment: What does run locally mean? You should be able to test your code independent of the ingress network layer

Comment: you are right, I can do this, but first I should do a build, then call main function, and after that I can do test, In the number of function, It is a litter bad way I think

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of how to do that locally:

```
doctl serverless functions invoke <function_name>
```

In order to see your functions list you can type:

```
doctl serverless functions list
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't run your function locally in an environment that reproduces the "server" execution. You just have to test your code locally like you would any other code.

But then you have to `doctl sls deploy` and run via the dashboard or `doctl sls functions invoke <fn>`, and you may come across new errors.

Even after you debug using the dashboard or `doctl sls functions invoke <fn>` to trigger, but you might also find that triggering your function directly (via browser/curl/$.get/fetch) can differ from the behaviour when triggered via the dashboard. The lack of logs for failed invocations is annoying. When I experienced that, my answer was to ensure I followed the [Parameters and Responses](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/functions/reference/parameters-responses/) docs.